# First Style in an SCSS File is Ignored

Tags: sass

I am using SCSS for my website styles and I am having an issue where the first rule in the file is ignored, here is the start of my file:

```
@import "_variables";
@import "_mixins";

a.mobile-nav__link:nth-child(2) {
  display: none !important;
}
```

The display none is visible in the source if I view it but doesn't actually take effect. I had to do this to make it work:

```
@import "_variables";
@import "_mixins";
a.mobile-nav__link:nth-child(2) {
  display: none !important;
}
a.mobile-nav__link:nth-child(2) {
  display: none !important;
}
```

So it seems like the first rule is just being ignored. Does anyone have any ideas what would cause this?

I am compiling the file to CSS and exporting it withint  tags on the page so I can see the css style but it just doesn't take and if I look for the style using the code inspector there is nothing applying the display property.

Any ideas are appreciated thank you!

Comment: Consider providing your `_mixins` code or the compiled CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out a space entity character was being inserted during the output at the start of the css file, making the first selector invalid. I sanitized that with PHP during the output and the issue was corrected.